# What is the meaning of confusion matrix that I got using 5 classes for the classification?

Tags: scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I have been working on a classification problem. As a newbie in Machine Learning, I just came across Confusion Matrix, I put the data and arguments as mentioned in their documentation. But I am confused that what really is the meaning of it.

P.S. I am working on classification problem having 5 classes to predict images.

I use the code below. The images of the output is also given below.

```py
# Confusion Matrix
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
cm = confusion_matrix(tr_int,prediction)
```

You can check the heat map here -> [Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmoU5.jpg).
And the image of confusion matrix array here-> [ConfusionMatrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWFWr.jpg)
The code I'm using for plotting is given below.

```py
import itertools
def plot_con(cm,classes,normalize=False,title="Confusion Matrix", cmap = plt.cm.Blues):
    plt.imshow(cm,interpolation='nearest', cmap=cmap)
    plt.title(title)
    plt.colorbar()
    tick_marks = np.arange(len(classes))
    plt.xticks(tick_marks, classes, rotation = 45)
    plt.yticks(tick_marks,classes)

    if normalize: 
        cm = cm.astype('float')/ cm.sum(axis = 1)[:, np.newaxis]
        print("Normalized C Matrix")
    else:
        print("Without Normalization")

    print(cm)

    thresh = cm.max() / 2.
    for i, j in itertools.product(range(cm.shape[0]),range(cm.shape[1])):
        plt.text(j, i, cm[i,j],
                horizontalalignment = "center"
                color = "white" if cm[i,j] > thresh else "black")

    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.ylabel('True Label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted')
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have so many 0's in your confusion matrix?

Comment: That's my question ... I am confused about this.

Comment: Show the output of `np.unique(tr_int)` and `np.unique(prediction)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your vectors `tr_int` and `prediction`, I think there are 10 different values, as your confusion matrix has a dimension of 10*10. Each row and column of the matrix correspond of a different class.

Comment: I checked it the ```python set(tr_int)``` is {0,1,2,3,4}, however, it does have length which is equal to the predictions.